# Laravel get JSON array from database

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel

What is the best way in Laravel to store an array in your database? And how do I get the same array with a query?

I have a variable that's an array in an array:

```
$colors = array(array('green'), array('yellow', 'white'));
```

When I store $colors, my database (column type = json) save it as:

```
[["green"], ["yellow", "white"]]
```

But when I try to get it from a query, I couldn't get the same array as $colors.

My query:

```
$colors = DB::table('colors')
          ->where('id', '1')
          ->value('arraycolors');
```

I hope someone can help how to query an array. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your column type is truly `JSON`, then you likely want one of the [`JSON` Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses).

Comment: "_I couldn't get the same array as $colors_" What do you get instead? Have you tried Eloquent (and maybe casting to array)?

Comment: @brombeer when I output $colors[0] for example, I get [ as a output. And $colors[1] I get [ as output. It looks like he think $colors is text because it starts with [[

Comment: And when I output $colors, I get [["green"], ["yellow", "white"]].

Wishing solution is #colors [0] = 'green'

Comment: @Peppermintology also when column type is text, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the array data to a JSON string yourself, use the Laravel $casts parameter on your model: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

You should do something like this in your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'colors' => 'array',
];
```

And I recommend changing your migration to text instead of json column like so:

```
$table->text('colors')->nullable();
```